# Android How to save msg into local storage?

Tags: android, sqlite, local-storage

I'm pretty new to the Android developer. I'm currently making an simple message app. so i want to store all the text message I received from node server. I don't really now how should i do this.

the msg I received from node server is JSONObject like:

```
{"name":"XX", "id":"XX","message":"xxxxxxxx"}
```

and I'm using a Custom ArrayAdepter to display the text:

```
public class ChatArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Text> {

private TextView text,avatar;
private List<Text> msgcontx = new ArrayList<Text>();
private LinearLayout wrapper;

@Override
public void add(Textobject){
    msgcontx.add(object);
    super.add(object);
}

public ChatArrayAdapter(Context context,int textViewResourceId) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId);
}

public int getCount(){
    return this.msgcontx.size();
}

public Text getItem(int index){
    return this.msgcontx.get(index);
}

public View getView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent){
    View row = convertView;
    if(row == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_listview, parent,false);
    }
    wrapper = (LinearLayout)row.findViewById(R.id.wrapper);
    Text comment = getItem(position);

    avatar = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.avatar);
    avatar.setText(comment.userID);
    avatar.setVisibility(comment.left? View.VISIBLE: View.GONE);

    text = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.comment);
    text.setText(comment.comment);
    // chat background to be changed
    text.setBackgroundResource(comment.left ? R.drawable.bg_chat_recipient : R.drawable.bg_chat_sender );
    wrapper.setGravity(comment.left? Gravity.START : Gravity.END);

    return row;
}

  public Bitmap decodeToBitmap(byte[] decodedByte){
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByte, 0,decodedByte.length );

  }
}
```

now I don't know how should I store those msg I received from node server at local storage, and when i open the app, I want to also display the msg history.

should I use SQL? but how should I store the msg? put them in different rows?
I know it might be a dumb question, But I really don't know how to store the msg to local storage and read them again.

Anyone can give a brief introduction? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could use SQL. You could write straight to the local filesystem. It's a choice that depends on what your application needs, and a decision **you** need to make.

Comment: so if i write straight to the local, it's gonna be public and everyone would be able to see that write? So if I use the system database library, does android encrypt the message or I have to encrypt it myself?

Comment: The encryption has to be done on your end. But why do you need the messages to be encrypted on local storage, if the only one accessing the data is the local user? Unless you need maximum security in your application, encrypting locally stored messages will just slow I/O operations down. And any data you write to the app's private directory is *private*, but of course, people with root access could open those files quite easily.

Comment: @KennyWorden yeah...that's what I am thinking about. it'a very easy to root an Android phone and lots of ppl r doing that... But u r right, encryption will slow down the speed...So I'm still thinking about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use some kind of database.I recommend an sql db with an orm - it lets you create a database based on classes and eliminates the need in ton of sql.

I like [active android](http://www.activeandroid.com/), but also take a look at sugar orm.

You should have a messages table, and each row in the table will be a message.In an orm you define the message using a class. example code (using ActiveAndroid orm):

```
@Table(name="Messages")
class Message extends Model {
    String name;
    String id;
    String message;

    //the empty consructor is required by active android
    public Message(){
       super();
    }

}
```

to actually enter the messages into the databse you will need to parse the json and create Messages objects from them, then save them.To parse the json into the Message object you can use Gson or [logan square](https://github.com/bluelinelabs/LoganSquare).

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!! I'm going to check those libraries!!!  speaking about database, does it matter what database to use? because I think Android has sqlite database library. And also, should I need to worry about the location about the data i stored, does system choose the location automatically? is this visible to public?

Comment: it stores the database in application folder itself and yes it will be public it creates .db file which will be visible for user. you make it invisible by storing it in asset folder instead of sdcard.

Comment: @Shravankumar about this, some app would create a local folder inside the sdcard, some will store inside the data/com.app.***/   folder. do u know what's the differences? thanks!